# Styling Google Script Spreadsheet HTML form

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

The following code in Google Scripts of a Google Spreadsheet opens an HTML dialog:

```
function openEmailForm(nameTo, emailAddressTo) {
   Logger.log('openEmailForm ran!');

   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('EmailForm')
      //.setTitle('Send Email To: ' & nameTo & '(' & emailAddressTo & ')')
      .setHeight(480)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);


    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Send Email To: ' + nameTo + ' (' + emailAddressTo + ')');
      return;
 };
```

Using the HTML of the form I am able to style all body (and child) elements, as you can see in the attached picture - body background-color set to yellow, titles set to color green.

How can I style the html form itself: the form background and the form title ("Send email to...)? I don't seem to have access to style those. I identified their class names (with Firebug) but all CSS styles applied to them are ignored.

see attached image: [image]

This is the HTML of this form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

<style>
body {
    background-color: #fafab6; 
    }

.modal-dialog {
   background-color: #fafab6; 
}

.modal-dialog-title-text {
   color: green;
}

p.fieldLabel {
  color: green;
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body  onload="setFocusToTextBox()">
    <div>
      <form>
         <p class="fieldLabel">Subject:</p>
         <p><textarea id="subject" name="subject" cols="50" rows="1" autofocus></textarea></p>
         <p class="fieldLabel">Message:</p>
         <p><textarea id="body" name="body" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea></p>
         <br><input type="submit" value="Send" id="submitbutton" onmouseup="writeFormData()">
      </form>
    </div>

<script>

  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("subject").focus();
};

  window.setFocusToTextBox = function (){
    document.getElementById("subject").focus();
};


  window.writeFormData = function() {
    //console.log('writeFormData ran!');
    var emailSubject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var emailBody = document.getElementById("body").value;

    //google.script.host.close();
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dataWasWritten)
      .processEmailForm(emailSubject, emailBody);



  };

  window.dataWasWritten = function() {
    //console.log('dataWasWritten ran');
    //Utilities.sleep(3000);
    google.script.host.close();
  };


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can access the modal style. that's outside the Html that you are inserting. However you could add the same message inside your html and it would be displayed with the styles you need. check this documentation  on how to communicate with the server so you can get the user's email: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: Thanks, Gerardo. I'm familiar with this guide. I'd like to keep the simple form and use HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile. Frustrating that some basic html elements are not accessible for styling, one way or another...